# How to set the version of an output MP3 file in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, stereo, mono

I want to split a stereo MP3 file into two mono MP3 files using FFmpeg such that each of the mono files is MPEG-1 Layer 3 Version 1:

I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -map_channel 0.0.0 left.mp3 -map_channel 0.0.1 right.mp3
```

The input file is MPEG-1 Layer 3 Version 1 but the out puts are MPEG-1 Layer 3 Version 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t set it. FFmpeg choses the version automatically based on the desired output. to force a version, you must use options compatible with that version. [Read this link](https://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html) (intro from that page below) and choose the correct combination that works for your application.

> Within an MPEG audio file, there is no main header, as an MPEG audio
>   file is just built up from a succession of smaller parts called
>   frames. Each frame is a datablock with its own header and audio
>   information.
>
> In the case of Layer I or Layer II, frames are totally independent
>   from each other, so you can cut any part of an MPEG audio file and
>   play it correctly. The player will then play the music starting from
>   the first full valid frame it will find. However, in the case of Layer
>   III, frames are not always independant. Due to the possible use of the
>   "byte reservoir", wich is a kind of internal buffer, frames are often
>   dependent of each other. In the worst case, 9 input frames may be
>   needed before beeing able to decode one single frame.
>
> If you need to retrieve information about an MPEG audio file, you
>   might simply locate the first frame, and retrieve information from its
>   header. Information within other frames should be consistent with the
>   first one, except for the bitrate, as you might be retrieving
>   information from a variable bitrate (VBR) file. In a VBR file, the
>   bitrate can be changed in each frame. It can be used, as an exemple,
>   to keep a constant sound quality during the whole file, by using more
>   bits when the music is more complex and thus requires more bits to be
>   encoded with a similar quality.
>
> The frame header itself is 32 bits (4 bytes) length. The first twelve
>   bits (or first eleven bits in the case of the MPEG 2.5 extension) of a
>   frame header are always set to 1 and are called "frame sync". Frames
>   may also feature an optional CRC checksum. It is 16 bits long and, if
>   it exists, immediately follows the frame header. After the CRC comes
>   the audio data. By re-calculating the CRC and comparing its value to
>   the sored one, you can check if the frame has been altered during
>   transmission of the bitstream.

Comment: So, can you tell me the command for producing the desired output?